# 2d convolutional minimum sum operation?

Tags: terminology, convolution

Suppose I have a $(2n+1)\times (2n+1)$ matrix $Y$, indexed by $\{-n, \cdots, n \} \times \{-n, \cdots, n \}$.

And I have another set of vectors $X = (x_1, x_2, \cdots, x_n)$, where $x_i \in \mathbb{R}^k$, where $k\leq n$.

The operation I'm interested in:

1, fill the $Y_0$ with all $+\infty $, except for $Y_0[0,0] = 0$.

2, iteratively get $x_t \in X$.

3, "convolutional sum", update
$$
Y_t[i, j] = min( Y_{t-1}[i-o, j] + x_t[o], \\
                 Y_{t-1}[i+o, j] + x_t[o], \\
                 Y_{t-1}[i, j-o] + x_t[o], \\
                 Y_{t-1}[i, j+o] + x_t[o], \\
                   Y_{t-1}[i, j]),\\
 \forall o \in [0, k]
$$

Is there a standard name for this operation?

To illustrate the operation scope, I made a visual plotting with $n=15, k=5$. And I only keep the first 3 steps.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the 1d version, it's called the (min,+) convolution. Details in [communication networking](https://www.amazon.in/Communication-Networking-Analytical-Approach-Kaufmann/dp/0124287514)

Define the (min,+) convolution of two real valued functions (domain is $\mathbb{R}^+$) f,g as
$$f*g= \inf_{0 \leq s \leq t}\{ f(s) + g(t-s)\}$$

Also in algorithms, the 1d version is [MinCov problem](https://drops.dagstuhl.de/opus/volltexte/2017/7421/pdf/LIPIcs-ICALP-2017-22.pdf).

Input: Sequences: $(a[i])^{n−1}_{i=0} , (b[i])^{n−1}_{i=0}$

Task: Output sequence $(c[i])^{n−1}_{i=0}$ , such that $c[k] = \text{min}_{i+j=k}(a[i] + b[j])$